# compare count of two mysql queries in one query

Tags: mysql

I've got stuck some where in mysql query. I'm having two queries and both are returning results fine.

My requirement is I want to use both query in one query so that I could compare count of both queries.

1st query

```
SELECT 
      user_profile.USERID, 
      user_profile.FIRSTNAME, 
      user_profile.LASTNAME,
      lastvisit.lastvisit,
      lastvisit.SOURCE as "RegistrationPlatform"  
    FROM user_profile
    INNER JOIN lastvisit
   ON user_profile.USERID =lastvisit.USERID
    WHERE MONTH(lastvisit.lastvisit) = 5 AND YEAR(lastvisit.lastvisit) = 2016
    AND lastvisit.SOURCE IN ('Online', 'MobileApp')
```

2nd query

```
SELECT 
      user_profile.USERID, 
      user_profile.FIRSTNAME, 
      user_profile.LASTNAME,
      user_profile.registrationDate,
      lastvisit.SOURCE as "RegistrationPlatform"  
    FROM user_profile
    INNER JOIN lastvisit
   ON user_profile.USERID =lastvisit.USERID
    WHERE MONTH(user_profile.registrationDate) = 5 AND YEAR(user_profile.registrationDate) = 2016
    AND lastvisit.SOURCE IN ('Online', 'MobileApp')
```

Output should be like this

```
Query   UserCount
Query1  100
Query2  200
```

Any suggestions please ?

Thanks

Comment: Show the queries and some sample data with expected result

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the first Union's (the first block's) column names are the ones iced for the final output

Answer (score 1):

use `Count(*)` and `Union`

```
SELECT 
    'query1' as query
    Count(*) as UserCount
    FROM user_profile
    INNER JOIN lastvisit
   ON user_profile.USERID =lastvisit.USERID
    WHERE MONTH(lastvisit.lastvisit) = 5 AND YEAR(lastvisit.lastvisit) = 2016
    AND lastvisit.SOURCE IN ('Online', 'MobileApp')
UNION
SELECT 
    'query2' as query
    Count(*)
    FROM user_profile
    INNER JOIN lastvisit
   ON user_profile.USERID =lastvisit.USERID
    WHERE MONTH(user_profile.registrationDate) = 5 AND YEAR(user_profile.registrationDate) = 2016
    AND lastvisit.SOURCE IN ('Online', 'MobileApp')
```